# How do each comment get their own box? (html, node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

The code now makes the comment box look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEti0.png)(pic 2). If I move the for-loop under the tweetBox, it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keOJS.png)(pic 3). The pink is the tweetBox, every tweet should have one, and the black is the tweetPanel where the text is displayed. I want it to look like pic 1. How should I do it?

When using jQuery, I used prepend to add new tweets at the top. Is there a similar method in Node.js so I can order the tweets by newest first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output looks weird because you're missing a closing `div` tag in your loop, and if you want to reverse the order of your list, you can just turn your for loop around by counting down to 0 instead of counting up to length, i.e.

```
<% for(var i=tweets.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {%>
    <div class='tweetBox'>
      <div class='tweetPanel'>
      <p><span><%= tweets[i].tweet %></span></p>
      <h3>
        <span>Tweeted by <%= tweets[i].name %></span>
        <span>- <%= tweets[i].date %></span>
      </h3>
      </div>
   </div>
<% } %>
<div class='clear'></div>
```

Comment: I tried to do the same on the loop earlier, but it was a - 1 I was missing. Thank you! I moved the div clear right before the last closing div and everything worked fine now. Thank you again.